# Which way to Rotate Vertical Blinds during the Cold Winter?

Tags: windows, blinds, curtain-rail

Which way do you rotate vertical blinds during the winter? I wanted to keep the place warmer, and keep cold air out. Should the Curved edges of the vane

1. Curved edges be turned towards you, facing away from the window?
2. Curved edges be turned away from you, facing towards the window?

Or does it really matter?

This is for heat insulation.

Comment: Doubt if it matters that much,but curved toward window, blinds not that good.  If window is drafty, then can seal it with window film or fix/seal the drafts/leaks.  For heat retention, probably need insulating curtains(tough with blinds).

Comment: Yeah..."Rotate" them into storage, and hang up a quilt. Or use heat shrink film if the window is leaky/drafty, and then hang up a quilt at night. Shrink-film tip - use good quality tape. We'd get the cheap film kit (because the film seemed to be no worse) and "replacement tape" from the big name brand that makes a lot of tape. Was cheaper than getting the top-brand kit, and worked just as well. I don't mind having better windows where that sort of thing is not needed, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The practical effect is going to be near zero difference but theoretically you'd want the isolated air space to be bigger.

Air foils or air spaces do have resistance to heat flow so by having the air space bigger you'd technically have more insulation, however, air is not a great insulator.

Comment: I would only add that you would want to face them so that any draft is moving away from where you are sitting.

Comment: Having the air gap bigger is not necessarily better. The reason being, that air _is_ actually a pretty good insulator, it's just that when air is in motion, the convection currents bring air that was in contact with warm surfaces to the colder surfaces - transferring heat. If you reduce the air-gap to a size that is too small to support convection currents, then you can maximize the insulation value of air. So, bigger is not always better.